# Org entry found only from its own buffer

Tags: org-babel

I tried to detangle (`org-babel-detangle`) a latex file and got
the error message

> Cannot find entry with ID "......."

with the ID of the subtree of the first block.  But the entry
does exist in the original org file.  What's more puzzling is
that this happens on one machine and not on another, with
exactly the same files.

Moreover, if I minimalize the file, the problem persists, but, if I
create a new file with the same structure, detangling works as
expected.

Also, if evaluate `(org-id-find '452031425...)` in the org
buffer, the entry is found, but, if I evaluate the same
expression in the tangled buffer, it returns `nil`.  What am I
missing?

Comment: From what I can see, there is no need for an ID at all - am I mistaken? The link that is inserted in the .tex file looks like this: `% [[file:/tmp/foo3.org::*This is a test][This is a test:1]]` and the comment at the end of the tangled block is `% This is a test:1 ends here` - maybe add  (a portion of) the tex file to your question? Also what `:comments` setting do you use? I used `noweb` for the above.

Comment: @NickD, the comment has the form `[[id:c3abd.....][title:1]]`  i think because i've set `org-id-link-to-org-use-id`

Answer (score -1):

When first using an org file on a new system, containing IDs one
wishes to track, one must evaluate

```
(org-id-update-id-locations '("file.org"))
```